# how to prevent the HS_checkbox to be checked unless a button2 has been clicked

Tags: c#

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                        
        this.Size = new Size(1069, 754);

        if (dataGridView3.Rows != null)
        { MessageBox.Show("Don't cLick again before rest the grid", "Alret"); }

        int count = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; x++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(SnH))
            {
                dataGridView3.Columns.Add("", "Load of " + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(SnC))
            {
                dataGridView4.Columns.Add("", "Load of " + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }

        }
    }       

private void HS_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!HS.Checked)
        {
            dataGridView3.Rows.Clear();
            return;
        }
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a boolean field that in button2_Click it's value become true or false.
and in HS_CheckedChanged check that boolean's value